# Maximize error with chrome and blender under Gnome 3

Tags: gnome, google-chrome, blender, maximized

Images say a 1000 words:

[image: blender]
[image: chrome]

This happens after I maximize the window, the content of the window is moved a little to the right. This only happens with chrome and blender (didn't happen with older releases of chrome, only the newest one). Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bug in amd driver that is causing this, I switched to open source driver.

Answer (score 1):

You use blender with the open source drivers? Does it even compare in performance?

Anyway, until this is fixed you may open and then close the preferences windows and this will fix it for tha main blender window. The preferences window will also get caught in this this situation if you miximize it but you can live without doing that anyway.

Comment: funny thing, open source driver is way faster on my pc than fglrx, even when it comes to playing 3d games, tho no vsync...